# Assigned a value to a variable in IF condition which never changes

Tags: if-statement, variables, conditional-statements, pine-script, tradingview-api

I am using a variable in the Tradingview pine script whose value change after an IF statement is true.

```
var x = 0
if ltp > 100  // ltp = Last Trade Price
  x := 1
```

If ltp goes above 100 then the value of 'x' becomes 1 but the problem is that if the next minute ltp is less than 100 then the value of 'x' again becomes 0. Whereas I want that once the value of 'x' becomes 1, then even if the value of ltp goes below 100, 'x' should not return to 0.
Is it possible?

Comment: When you say "the next minute" is it still the same bar?

Comment: Yes, fr same bar

Answer (score 0):

pinescript does not allow saving of data in variables between bars. In your case, if your bar is 4h, you can save it for 240 minutes, but if you are looking at 1m bar chart, you will not be able to save it for next minute.
To do something like that, try using a state change flag and varip( a variable that keeps its value for duration of the bar)

```
varip x = 0
varip stateNotChangedThisBar = true
if ltp > 100 and stateNotChangedThisBar // ltp = Last Trade Price
    x := 1
    stateNotChangedThisBar  := false
```

In this case, IF above will execute only the first time price goes above 100, then this flag will prevent it from executing until bar closes.